# I want to get the download url of image from firebase storage ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using firebase to upload some images, and its work fine, but the problem I can not get the download url of the image

here my code

```
@IBAction func btnUploadImgsAction(_ sender: UIButton) {


    let url1 = uploading(img: Img1)
    print("///////////img 1   //////// \(url1)   ////////")
    let url2 = uploading(img: Img2)
    print("///////////img 2   //////// \(url2)   ////////")
    let url3 = uploading(img: Img3)
    print("///////////img 3   //////// \(url3)   ////////")
    let url4 = uploading(img: Img4)
    print("///////////img 4   //////// \(url4)   ////////")


}


func uploading( img : UIImageView)-> String{
    var strURL = ""
    let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString
    let storeImage = self.storageRef.child("profile_Images").child(imageName)

    if let uploadImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation((img.image)!){
        storeImage.putData(uploadImageData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metaData, error) in
            storeImage.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                if let urlText = url?.absoluteString {

                     strURL = urlText
                    print("///////////tttttttt//////// \(strURL)   ////////")


                }
            })
        })


    }

    return strURL
}
```

when I print the strURL inside the uploading method the url comes but when I printed in the btnUploadImgsAction its not coming, What am donig wrong ?? 
please help thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46146043/7715250 same logic

Comment: You are calling Asynchronous method within your method and trying to get return in synchronous method

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should create a closure method instead method which directly returns string because this method is async method

Your method declaration should be something like below

```
func uploading( img : UIImageView, success: (url: String) -> Void) {
 // return with clouser
 success(url: strurl)
}
```

Updated with your method

```
func uploading( img : UIImageView, completion: @escaping ((String) -> Void)) {
    var strURL = ""
    let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString
    let storeImage = self.storageRef.child("profile_Images").child(imageName)

    if let uploadImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation((img.image)!){
        storeImage.putData(uploadImageData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metaData, error) in
            storeImage.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                if let urlText = url?.absoluteString {

                    strURL = urlText
                    print("///////////tttttttt//////// \(strURL)   ////////")

                    completion(strURL)
                }
            })
        })
    }
}
```

And function call would be

```
let str = uploading(img: imageObject) { (url) in
     print(url)
 }
```

Comment: @Rooh If my answer helped you, Mark it as Correct Answer