# firebase swift empty array out of observer

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my viewController I have an array of class Users named arrayUtenti, with the code below I need to add that user to that array but for some reason that i cannot understand I get an empty array, what could happened?

**************EDITED  WORKS**************

```
func vengodaEditPremuto(completionHandler:@escaping ([Users]) -> ()){    self.root.child("users").child("ZJq98gvOEHaLUqYTbp4xF52f2K23").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

var TempArray: [Users] = []


        guard
            let value = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject],
            let userid = value["id"],
            let username = value["name"],
            let useremail = value["email"]
        else {return}

  let utenteesistente = Users(id: userid as? String, name: username as? String, email: useremail as? String)


   TempArray.append(utenteesistente)



   self.arrayUtenti = TempArray
   completionHandler(self.arrayUtenti) 
   print(self.arrayUtenti) //here is ok

    })

 print(self.arrayUtenti) //here the array is empty!!
 }
```

Comment: yes your function is async. check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46146043/7715250 you have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine after my comment. This is the last thing you need to do to make a correct call:

```
vengodaEditPremuto(){ result in
print(result)
}
```