# Return value when asynchronous tasks are completed

Tags: ios, swift

I want to implement  performFetchWithCompletionHandler in my appdelegate. I want to do something like this

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

DownloadManager.shared.startDownload(completion: { (done) in
if done{
completionHandler(.newData)
                }else{
                    completionHandler(.noData)
                }
})
```

I am not sure how to implement this on my `DownloadManager`. Its actual implementation looks like

```
class DownloadManager{
    var pagesDownloadCompleted = false
    var imagesDownloadCompleted = false

// Function  to start the download     
    func startDownload(date: DataToDownload){
        ...
        downloadPages(pages)
        downloadImages(images)
    }
    }

// Function  to download the pages 
    func downloadPages(pages: Pages){
        ....
        if completed{
            pagesDownloadCompleted = true
        }
}

// Function  to download the images      
    func downloadImages(images: Images){
        ....
        if completed{
            imagesDownloadCompleted = true
        }
}

// Function  to check if the doanload is done       
    func downloadCompleted() -> Bool{
        return pagesDownloadCompleted == true && imagesDownloadCompleted ==  true
    }
    }
}
```

A possible solution is to start downloading the pages, when I am done I start downloading the images, and when the images are done I return true. But downloading the images and the pages will not be parallel. Do you see any other solution?

Comment: You can use a dispatch group with a dispatch group `notify` to call your completion handler when everything is done.

Comment: OK... I'm not sure what's going on with your code as the brackets don't match up. I know you have removed some code (with the ...) which is fine. But can you please make sure that the rest of the code makes sense. Thanks :)

Comment: A poor code presentation + a serious typo in the topic title

Comment: I updated the code, hope its more clear. I can't post the hole code because it's huge and not interesting in this case

Comment: My answer should guide you enough: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46145883/firebase-printing-wrong-number-of-users-in-database-when-counting-users-in-arr/46146043#46146043

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this, you still need to handle failed and data flow though, try to use dispatch group is another solution also:

```
class DownloadManager {
    var pagesDownloadCompleted = false
    var imagesDownloadCompleted = false

    // Function  to start the download
    func startDownload(date: String, completion: (_ completed: Bool)->()){

        downloadPages(pages: page) { (completed) in
            if completed {
                pagesDownloadCompleted = true
            }
            self.downloadCompleted(completion: completion)
        }
        downloadImages(images: image) { (completed) in
            if completed {
                imagesDownloadCompleted = true
            }
            self.downloadCompleted(completion: completion)
        }
    }

    // Function  to download the pages
    func downloadPages(pages: Pages, completion: (_ completed: Bool)->()){

        completion(true) //When download finished
    }

    // Function  to download the images
    func downloadImages(images: Images, completion: (_ completed: Bool)->()){

        completion(true) //When download finished
    }

    // Function  to check if the doanload is done
    func downloadCompleted(completion: (_ completed: Bool)->()){
        if pagesDownloadCompleted == true && imagesDownloadCompleted == true {
            completion(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO this kind of problem is best solved using `DispatchGroup`. Whenever you start a download, call `enter`, when that's finished call `leave`. `group.notify` is used to determine when all downloads are done.

```
class DownloadManager{
    var group = DispatchGroup()

    func startDownload(date: DataToDownload) {
        downloadPages(pages)
        downloadImages(images)

        group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
            // all downloads completed
        }
    }

    // Function  to download the pages
    func downloadPages(_ pages: Pages){
        group.enter()
        // do the download, when done, call:
        group.leave()
    }

    // Function  to download the images
    func downloadImages(_ images: Images){
        group.enter()
        // do the download, when done, call:
        group.leave()
    }
}
```